# How does this equation yield into the following

Tags: quadratics

$\frac{(a^2 + b^2)} {(ab + 1)} = k$

becomes

$x^2-kb \cdot x + (b^2 - k) = 0$

in an example I am attempting to understand, can you please clarify how the quadratic equation follows from the equation above?

Comment: Is this Vieta jumping?

Comment: Yes, this a step in the overall problem

Comment: see here https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/vieta-root-jumping-2/

Comment: I suppose $x=a$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what I am not understanding is how the equation is derived in order to get to the lemma

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yeah, x = a when the equation is fixed for b and k and manipulated for a

Comment: Try this: (1) multiply both sides by $ab+1$. (2) substract $kab+k$ from both sides.